# Pandas initialize multiple columns at once

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I need to create two (or more) new columns both of which are initialized to zero. This is what I am doing to reach there -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': {0: 0.6, 1: 0.5, 2: -0.7, 3: 0.6, 4: 0.7, 5: -0.7, 6: 0.9, 7: 0.5, 8: -0.6, 9: 0.5, 10: 0.6, 11: -0.5, 12: 0.5, 13: -0.6}, '_bare_nuclei': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0}, '_bland_chromatin': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0}, '_cell_shape_uniformity': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0}, '_cell_size_uniformity': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 0}, '_clump_thickness': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 1}})

new_cols = ['_normal_nucleoli', '_epithelial_cell_size', '_mitoses']
df.loc[:,new_cols] = 0
```

I thought this would work and give me the results I wanted. But I am getting the following error.

```
KeyError: "['_normal_nucleoli' '_epithelial_cell_size' '_mitoses'] not in index"
```

It says that these keys are not present in the `index`. I don't understand this part. Why does the error say `index`? I am accessing the `columns` here.

But, more importantly, how do I create multiple columns without using a loop. I know I can create the new columns using -

```
for each_new_col in new_cols:
    df.loc[:,each_new_col] = 0
```

or by using `df.assign`
But is there a simpler way (without loops, etc) to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can quite easily use `assign` here (without a loop):

```
df = df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(new_cols, 0))
```

Where,

```
print(dict.fromkeys(new_cols, 0))
{'_epithelial_cell_size': 0, '_mitoses': 0, '_normal_nucleoli': 0}
```

You'd need to unpack the dictionary when passing it to `assign`, since the function accepts keyword arguments only.

Comment: awesome, this works. I tried using the `new_cols` list directly and it instead created a variable called `new_cols`. Didn't know about the `dict` way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: @ClockSlave Sure, np :)

Answer (score 3):

If order of new columns is important use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(0, columns=new_cols, index=df.index))
```

Comment: nice to see you after a while! (+1)